# xCode 7.1: Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMaps'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I am using the GoogleMaps iOS SDK in my app and added it with cocoapods. However, after updating xCode from 7.0 to 7.1 I'm suddenly getting the following error: *Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMaps'*

In addition xCode also gives me an error in the GoogleMaps.h file in the GoogleMaps.framework:
[Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GoogleMaps'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeF0H.png)

I already deleted my DerivedData folder, updated cocoapods, reinstalled the GoogleMaps iOS SDK and cleaned and build the framework's scheme and my app's scheme. But nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in this similar question: [xCode 7 error: include of non-modular header inside framework module with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292679/xcode-7-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module-with-google/33293721#33293721)

...but essentially you'll need to create an Objective-C bridging header file whereas you may not have needed one with Xcode 7.0. The why still eludes me.

Comment: Yes the workaround of adding an Objective-C bridging header solved the issue for me. But it seems like it's a bug in the framework: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8524&can=1&q=Could%20not%20build%20Objective-C%20module&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Answer (score 0):

you should open the .xcworkspace not .xcodeproj
once you added cocoa pods your project folder will contain the .xcworkspace file