# xCode 7 error: include of non-modular header inside framework module with Google Maps

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, xcode7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I updated to xCode 7.1 today and tried to build my app but I'm getting this error:

[image]

I have already tried going to Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES but that didn't solve this issue.

UPDATE: Since this was preventing me from compiling and hindering my progress in terms of development, I recommend you download an older version of xCode from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ make sure to login). You can download version 7.0.1 from the link and at least continue development.

This is what I've done and I can continue development.

I know this is not a fix, but its workaround for the people who wish to continue development.

Comment: I have a dream that one day we'll stop wasting two days of work just to make Xcode happy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has updated its SDK to 1.10.5, Just Reinstall Pod and it should work fine. I was facing same issue and now all issues are fixed after pod reinstallation.

Comment: Thanks, but their release notes section does not even have it documented - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases

Comment: They might have updated few hours ago. I am too waiting for official documentation update.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: This shuold be the accepted answer. Fixed my issue and no need of bridging header, you can use it as a module `import GoogleMaps`

Answer (score 9):

I ended up having to create an Objective-C bridging header file and adding `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` whereas I hadn't needed one previously since I was using Cocoapods in a Swift project and the `use_frameworks!` setting had previously taken care of this.

Here's instructions for how to create the Objective-C bridging header file: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: that's amazing, it's work=) I don't understand just one, if I load the lib through CocaoPod why I should import else in the bridge file?

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23554

Just remove the header search paths in build settings. In new Xcode versions (after 7.0 I guess) you need to look for the headers by linking frameworks and not by linking header files directly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was resolved by:

1. Product > Clean              (cmd k)
2. Product > Clean Build Folder (cmd opt k)
3. Product > Run                (cmd r)

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me after quite a long time of digging into this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3847)  may be useful.

I tried a few things, but I'm not positive which one fixed the issues.
First, I edited my Podfile to include:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```

Then, I added a bridging header file, with one line:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

Cleaned and rebuilt the project and that did the trick.