# Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.1 Google Maps SDK

Tags: xcode, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

While Xcode was version 7.0 I had an app that worked perfectly well. I made the cocoapod file, set it up and everything ran perfect.

I just updated to 7.1 and now all I get are 21 errors that say "/Users/Johnathan/Desktop/Parse Default/GoogleMaps/Google Maps/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Headers/GoogleMaps.h:14:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GoogleMaps'"

I'm not sure what to do or how to update/edit this. I am not very familiar with cocoapods. Please help. I can't get my app to run. Thanks.

And if it helps all I did was update Xcode and it went from working to not working.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread below for a solution as it seems to be most up to date.

In essence, you will need to add a Bridge Header (see comment 7)

Here it is: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8524&can=1&q=Could%20not%20build%20Objective-C%20module&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: As well here is a simular question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292679/xcode-7-error-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module-with-google/33293721#33293721

Comment: To follow up, this did not seem to solve my problem, so I downloaded the previous version of the Xcode and reinstalled it to continue working until a clear solution is determined.